# Unity error with Firebase RealTime Database

Tags: c#, android, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I have been using Unity for a year now and have decided to make a simple chat app. I decided to use Google's Firebase to store my user and chat data. I plan to have the app on android(iOS in the future). My problem is with Unity not being able to generate a Firebase Android File. I searched the error up and it took me to [this website](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65148274/unity-generation-of-the-firebase-android-resource-file-google-services-xml-from). I did the recommend solution and created the realtime database and re installed the json and plist files. It did not work. I still get the following error.

> Generation of the Firebase Android resource file google-services.xml from /Users/Family/Desktop/கலைமாறன்/Unity/STEMastery/Assets/../Assets/Firebase Data/google-services.json failed.
> If you have not included a valid Firebase Android resources in your app it will fail to initialize.

```
"python" "/Users/Family/Desktop/கலைமாறன்/Unity/STEMastery/Library/PackageCache/com.google.firebase.app@7.2.0/Firebase/Editor/generate_xml_from_google_services_json.py" -i "/Users/Family/Desktop/கலைமாறன்/Unity/STEMastery/Assets/../Assets/Firebase Data/google-services.json" -o "/Users/Family/Desktop/கலைமாறன்/Unity/STEMastery/Assets/../Assets/Plugins/Android/FirebaseApp.androidlib/res/values/google-services.xml" -p "com.maranstudios.stemastery.maran" ...
```

I also checked the external tools. Under android it says JDK installed with Unity, Android SDK tools installed with Unity, Android NDK Installed with Unity and Gradle Installed with Unity. I also donwloaded the android studio so I can build to android.

I have also tried to restarted unity, visual studio and even my computer, but that did not help.

Unity runs the program perfectly well on my iMac and can access my RealTime Database in the unity editor. But when I run it on my phone 2 errors pop up.

1. DllNotFound Exception: Firebase CppApp ...
2. It can not find the default reference.

2's Explanation:
I have this line of code.

```
DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.RootReference;
```

I then check in another script if t hat is null. It becomes null on my phone, but works fine on my mac.

I am using macOS Mojave (Version 10.14.4).
My unity version is Unity 2020.3.4f1.
My phone uses android 10.

I have tried everything that I can think of to deal with this error. I believe that by fixing this error, my app will work properly on my phone. I have tried to give all the information needed to help you understand my issues. If I am still missing any, please ask and I will respond as soon as possible.

EDIT :
I tried a couple new things. I upgraded to unity 2020.7, but that did not work. I also tried to create a new project from scratch using Unity 2019, but I am still getting that same error. Could it be that Firebase just doesn't work on my mac or is that this a bug in Unity that has somehow existed over several versions? I really could use some help figuring out to integrate Firebase. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue with developers who have non-ascii usernames. See [this issue](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/issues/1007) and [this issue](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity/issues/690). It might be worth opening a new issue and highlighting that it's blocking active development right now (note for future readers, the first issue is closed but the second is open as I write. If `690` is also closed with a milestone associated, this means that the issue has been fixed).

For potential workarounds, the best known workaround would be to use a username without any extended non-ascii characters. I know that this can be problematic or disruptive.

You may try disabling persistence in the Editor before making any database calls. This might prevent Firebase from trying to read your local data folder, avoiding the issue:

```
var database = FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance;
if (Application.isEditor) {
    database.SetPersistenceEnabled(false);
}
var reference = database.RootReference;
```

You only have to do this once for your game (so maybe immediately after `CheckAndFixDependenciesAsync`), but putting it right before database access should makes my example code safer.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for replying. I thought this issue would be forgotten after a few days. I will see if I can try that. But I do have one question. What do you mean non-ascii usernames or what are ascii usernames?

Comment: I try to loop around StackOverflow when I can, but asking issues on GitHub is a good way to make sure they're at least addressed (you just have to reply to any questions within two weeks to keep issues open). For ascii, I mean the non-extended ascii character set ( http://www.asciitable.com/ ), basically Latin characters (and probably safest without accents). Since the desktop implementation is almost all C++, issues like this crop up where elements weren't converted to UTF-8 as a fallback.

Comment: (which, if you're not familiar, UTF-8 is a great fallback for languages that expect 8-bit characters. Outside of strlen being the _bytes_ a string takes rather than the _characters_, it's backwards-compatible-ish in a way that doesn't break code but may look weird)