# Generation of the Firebase Android resource file google-services.xml from Assets/GoogleService-Info.plist failed

Tags: android, ios, firebase, unity-game-engine, plist

I tried to integrated Firebase to my Unity project. I sure did integrate successfully many times before for other Unity projects. I create new firebase project step by step follow Firebase documents, but this time I kept getting this error:

*Generation of the Firebase Android resource file google-services.xml from Assets/GoogleService-Info.plist failed.
If you have not included a valid Firebase Android resources in your app it will fail to initialize.

"python3" "***/Assets/Firebase/Editor/generate_xml_from_google_services_json.py" -i "Assets/GoogleService-Info.plist" -l --plist

Could not find key in plist file: [CLIENT_ID]

You can start to diagnose this issue by executing ""python3" "***/Assets/Firebase/Editor/generate_xml_from_google_services_json.py" -i "Assets/GoogleService-Info.plist" -l --plist" from the command line.
UnityEngine.Debug:LogError (object)
Firebase.Editor.GenerateXmlFromGoogleServicesJson:RunResourceGenerator*

I compared file "GoogleService-Info.plist" to other project's and found that my "GoogleService-Info.plist" file missing key "CLIENT_ID". I searched for the error but I could not find the root cause. I also delete the firebase project then create another one but the content of file "GoogleService-Info.plist" was not changed.

What can I do to resolve this error? Thank you!

Comment: The plist file is used for iOS builds and the json file is used for Android builds. Are you sure you're building what you think you're building? I'd check in the Firebase console and make sure the package name you're using there matches what you're using in Unity and download the josn file again to be sure.

Comment: @RetiredNinja The error content may make us concern but this error content is similar with this error, the error I kept getting about missing "CLIENT_ID"
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65148274/unity-generation-of-the-firebase-android-resource-file-google-services-xml-from

Comment: Okay, except that they said they were building for iOS where you've said Android and their solution was to complete the setup in the Firebase console and download a new configuration file. Have you done so as I suggested earlier? Are you sure you're building for Android?

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm not sure I got you. I'm building for both Android and iOS. I have both "google-services.json" and "GoogleService-Info.plis" within my project. The error only show when I switch platform to iOS. But I checked and found that there's no key [CLIENT_ID] in both files. I tried to redownload both files but keep getting the error.

Comment: Just to make sure, could you please check that there are no spaces or numbers in the file name of GoogleService-Info.plist and confirm that you are building for iOS in the Build Settings menu?

Additionally, try removing your json file from the project while building for iOS and see if the reported error changes or disappears. Afterward, return the json file to the project.

How does the behaviour compare to previous observations?